# Why is the perturbation term taken as current density times magnetic vector potential in Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

When an electromagnetic field is applied to an electronic system, the Hamiltonian term of this perturbation is written as
$$
H'(t)=\int d\mathbf{r}  \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)\cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)
$$
here $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)$ is current density operator and $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)$ is vector potential that represents electromagnetic field.

I wonder why we write the perturbation as given in $H'(t)$? What is the exact derivation for this term? What if one is interested in non-linear perturbation terms (i.e. terms proportional to $\mathbf{A}^2$)?

Comment: This is not necessarily a pertubative term, this is the general coupling between a charged current and the gauge field, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_coupling , see also "Lagrangian for classical electrodynamics" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism